# Stopping of rabbitMQ application ( Ctrl-C)

Tags: spring-amqp

I was trying to find out what is the right way to stop a RabbitMQ applicaton safely if it is interrupted by interrupts like Ctrl-C or a normal shutdown

Is it enough I have an ApplicationContext.close  (  with a registered  hook )  which will implicitly take care about complete graceful shutdown from ConnectionFactory to Listeneres ?

I tried to implement destroy for only listeners as mentioned in some blogs

when I have a configuration like

```
<rabbit:listener-container connection-factory="connectionFactory" >

<rabbit:listener  id = "X" ref="onMessageX"    queue-names="Z" />
<rabbit:listener id = "A" ref="onMessageB"    queue-names="A" />
<rabbit:listener id= "C" ref="onMessageC"    queue-names="C" />

</rabbit:listener-container>
```

and when I tried

SimpleMessageListenerContainer  Container =  context.getBean(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.class);

I ended up getting 3 Container beans when  I expected one , each listener became a container.

I was able to close each using  stop after getting using getBeansOfType into  MAP and iterating. Shutdown happens if you keep it in destroy and applicationContext.close happens.

Am I trying to do something too complicated and stupid here ? What and all need to be stopped if we need to start stopping from connection factory.

Answer (score 0):

Your observation about `<rabbit:listener-container>` is fully correct. You have target `MessageListenerContainer`s as many as you specify `<rabbit:listener>` sub-elements there.

When `Ctrl-C` happens, the normal `ApplicationContext.close()` should do the work for your to stop all the containers gracefully.